# VBA Loop in Excel with Solver

Tags: vba, excel

So here is my issue.  I am trying to write a loop that performs a function using solver.  Basically it starts in one cell, runs solver, moves the target and constraint cells to the right one, solves, moves target and contraint cells to the right 14, solves, right one,  solves, right 14 solves, until it finds a blank.

Here is the first few lines of code to show you what I am doing in the long version.

```
Range("RI6").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$RI$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$RG$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RI$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RI$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("RJ16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$RJ$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$RJ$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RJ$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RJ$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("RX16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$RX$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$RX$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RX$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RX$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("RY16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$RY$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$RY$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RY$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RY$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("SM16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$SM$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$SM$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$SM$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$SM$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("SN16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$SN$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$SN$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$SN$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$SN$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("TB16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$TB$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$TB$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TB$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TB$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("TC16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$TC$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$TC$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TC$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TC$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("TQ16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$TQ$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$TQ$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TQ$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TQ$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("TR16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$TR$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$TR$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TR$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$TR$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("UF16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$UF$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$UF$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$UF$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$UF$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
Range("UG16").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$UG$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$UG$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$UG$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$UG$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
```

Thank you in advance for any help / advice.

Comment: You don't seem to have any question. Does your code actually work? If so -- you can shorten it by using a loop.

Comment: If you need help writing loops then you might want to look at the following website: http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html

Comment: My question is how to do the cell movement, I have tried to loop that and cannot get it working properly.  The code works when written out the long way, but not when I have attempted a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but perhaps something like...

```
Option Explicit

Sub SolverLop()
Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Integer
cnt = 0
For i = 477 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(16, i).Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:=Cells(16, i).Address, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Cells(1, i).Address, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Cells(1, i).Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve Userfinish:=True

    cnt = cnt + 1
    If cnt = 2 Then
        i = i + 14
        cnt = 0
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Make sure you have a reference to solver checked in Tools--> References--> Solver.

P.S.  477 is the column number associated with the starting column, "RJ", in your example above...To get the column number of any column just type the following into a blank cell `=column(indirect("A2"))` ...  Replace "A2" with the column you are wanting to find the number for.

Comment: I was working on something really similar but yours is cleaner.  You should share that 477 is the column number, or input a conversion so OP can just input the starting range and the column # is gathered from that.

Answer (score 0):

The first part looks different then the others, so I did not include it in the "loop", but it would be easy enough to add, if the differences were due to a typo.

```
    Range("RI6").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$RI$16", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:="$RG$1", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RI$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$RI$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
    SolverSolve (True)
```

So one way to loop would be as below:

```
    Dim Temp As String, TempArray As Variant

    TempArray = Array("RJ16", "RX16", "RY16", "SM16", "SN16", "TB16", "TC16", "TQ16", "TR16", "UF16", "UG16")
    For i = 0 To UBound(TempArray)
        Range(TempArray(i)).select
        Temp = Cells(1, Range(TempArray(i)).Column).Address
        SolverOk SetCell:=TempArray(i), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.15, ByChange:=Temp, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Temp, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="74"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=Temp, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="87"
        SolverSolve (True)
    Next i
```